# How to remove spaces in between the String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have below String

```
  string = "Book Your Domain And Get\n \n\n \n \n \n Online Today."
  string = str.replace("\\s","").trim();
```

which returning

```
  str = "Book Your Domain And Get     Online Today."
```

But what is want is

```
  str = "Book Your Domain And Get Online Today."
```

I have tried Many Regular Expression and also googled but got no luck. and did't find related question, Please Help, Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's with all the newline characters?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `\\s+` instead of `\\s` as there are two or more consecutive whitespaces in your input.

```
string = str.replaceAll("\\s+"," ")
```

Comment: @JayakrishnanPm That will remove all spaces, instead of replacing multiple consecutive spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `replaceAll` which takes a regex as parameter. And it seems like you want to replace multiple spaces with a single space. You can do it like this:

```
string = str.replaceAll("\\s{2,}"," ");
```

It will replace 2 or more consecutive whitespaces with a single whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

First get rid of multiple spaces:

```
String after = before.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove the white space between 2 words or characters and not at the end of string 
then here is the 
regex that i have used,

```
        String s = "   N    OR  15  2    ";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); 

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

        while(m.find()){
        String replacestr = "";


        int i = m.start();
            while(i<m.end()){
                replacestr = replacestr + s.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }

            m = pattern.matcher(s);
        }

        System.out.println(s);
```

it will only remove the space between characters or words not spaces at the ends
and the output is

> NOR152

Answer (score 0):

Eg. to remove space between words in a string:

`String example = "Interactive Resource";`

`System.out.println("Without space string: "+ example.replaceAll("\\s",""));`

Output:
 `Without space string: InteractiveResource`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a String without space, just add the argument sep='' to the print function, since this argument's default value is " ".

Answer (score 0):

```
//user this for removing all the whitespaces from a given string for example a =" 1 2 3 4"
//output: 1234 
a.replaceAll("\\s", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

String s2=" 1 2   3 4   5 ";
String after=s2.replace(" ", "");

this work for me

Comment: This is already covered by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string_a = "AAAA           BBB";
String actualTooltip_3 = string_a.replaceAll("\\s{2,}"," ");
System.out.println(String actualTooltip_3);
```

> OUTPUT will be:AAA BBB